# How to change attribute lang html using vue-i18n

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to change atttribute of html element from:

```
lang='en'
```

to

```
lang='jp'
```

when i change language using package vue-i18n.

I import plugins vue-i18n in nuxt.config.js and add attribute:

```
 htmlAttrs: {
    lang: this.$i18n.locale,
 },
```

in `head` object but it throw error: Cannot read property '$i18n' of undefined

This is my vue-i18n plugins:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default ({ app, store }) => {
    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: store.state.i18n.locale,
        fallbackLocale: 'vi',
        messages: {
            en: require('~/locales/en.json'),
            vi: require('~/locales/vi.json'),
            jp: require('~/locales/jp.json'),
        },
    });
};
```

Thanks you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

In the i18n configuration section of your `nuxt.config.js` file, set the `seo` attribute to `true` and the i18n module should take care of setting the html lang attribute for you.

```
i18n: {
   seo: true,
   ...
}
```

Nuxt i18n documentation: https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/seo.html#benefits

Comment: Actually, this answer is not answering what OP requested and this approach will only work with `nuxt-i18n`, which is available with same name in NPM or Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

if you consider use `htmlAttrs` not in `nuxt.config.js`, but in other file (i use `htmlAttrs` in `MainHeader.vue` in my the only layout, for example), so thisi is the code:

```
export default {
  name: 'MainHeader',
  head() {
    return {
      meta: [{
        hid: 'og:locale', property: 'og:locale', content: this.currentLocaleDecoding
      }],
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: this.currentLocale ? this.currentLocale : 'en'
      }
    }
  },
...
  computed: {
    currentLocale() {
      return this.$i18n.locale
    },
```